# Matplotlib - Scatter Points and text annotations are not aligning to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my clustering results, but the Scatter Points and text annotations are not aligning to each other. I am not sure, what values to add, or if there is any easy and correct method to do the same, below is my piece of code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
labs = statewise_us_finalDF_copy['State'].tolist()

#filter rows of original data
filtered_label0 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 0]
filtered_label1 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 1]
filtered_label2 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 2]
filtered_label3 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 3]
filtered_label4 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 4]
filtered_label5 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 5]
filtered_label6 = statewise_us_finalDF_copy[statewise_us_finalDF_copy['KMEANS_cluster'] == 6]
 
# Plotting the results
plt.scatter(filtered_label0['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label0['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'red')
plt.scatter(filtered_label1['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label1['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'blue')
plt.scatter(filtered_label2['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label2['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'green')
plt.scatter(filtered_label3['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label3['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'black')
plt.scatter(filtered_label4['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label4['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'magenta')
plt.scatter(filtered_label5['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label5['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'cyan')
plt.scatter(filtered_label6['Unemployed_2019'] , filtered_label6['POVALL_2019'] , color = 'orange')
plt.legend(['Cluster 1', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 3', 'Cluster 4', 'Cluster 5', 'Cluster 6', 'Cluster 7'], loc = 'best')

#use for loop to add annotations to each point in plot 
for i, txt in enumerate(labs):
    plt.annotate(txt, (statewise_us_finalDF_copy['Unemployed_2019'][i], statewise_us_finalDF_copy['POV017_2019'][i]))

    
plt.title('Clusters by Kmeans', fontsize = 30)    
plt.xlabel('Unmployment in 2019', fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('Poverty in 2019', fontsize = 18)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i, txt in enumerate(labs):
        xx = statewise_us_finalDF_copy['Unemployed_2019'][i]
        yy = statewise_us_finalDF_copy['POV017_2019'][i]
        ax.text(xx, yy, txt, transform=ax.transAxes, axis="both", direction='in',top=True, right=True)
```

Comment: fig and ax defined are not working for me throwing error

Comment: you can change also your plt.annotate as `plt.annotate(txt, (statewise_us_finalDF_copy['Unemployed_2019'][i], statewise_us_finalDF_copy['POV017_2019'][i]), xytext=(1,1))`. **xytext** controls text distance from point.